# Reload the page if on the same path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react app I have two `NavLink` tags as:

```
<NavLink exact={true} to={'/home'}>Home</NavLink>
<NavLink exact={true} to={'/users'}>Users</NavLink>
```

The navigation works fine but I want to reload the page if I click on the NavLink and I'm on the same path so if I'm on `/home` and click the `NavLink` of `/home` I want to reload the page.

Here's what I tried:

```
<NavLink onClick={linkClicked} exact={true} to={'/home'}>Home</NavLink>

const linkClicked = () => {
if(props.location.pathname === props.history.location.pathname) {
  window.location.reload();
 }
}
```

this is reloading the page but with some issue like it redirects back to the current page even on clicking a different path.
How can I fix this?

These are the routes:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home {...props} />} />
    <Route path="/users" render={(props) => <Users {...props} />} />
    <Redirect to="/home" />
  </Switch>
```

and here's the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dm9z1k?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if statement, just window.location.reload() will make the requirement fulfilled.

Try this,

```
<NavLink onClick={()=>window.location.reload()} exact={true} to={'/home'}>Home</NavLink>
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps!! Happy Coding!!.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, it's redirecting to the same page even on clicking a different NavLink

Comment: Did u try using `Link` instead of `NavLink` ? Remove `<Redirect to="/home" />` as this will always redirect you to home page on any instance.

Comment: If I remove `<Redirect to="/home">` how can I use this as the default route? If I open `localhost:3000` I want it to directly go to `localhost:3000/home`.

Comment: If that is the case then use this. `<Redirect exact from="/" to= "/home" />` and set other two routes as `exact={true}`.

Comment: The issue still persists.

Comment: Can you try placing the Redirect code right after switch statement? and please do add exact in all the routes.

Comment: Tried it...I think the issue is with how we're using `location.reload` when I'm clicking on a NavLink the path is changing correctly but at the same time the page is getting reloaded because of `onClick` so it is again changing the url to the current url.

Comment: Can you add your code in CodeSandbox and share the link ?

Comment: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dm9z1k?file=index.js)

Comment: Can you check the stackblitz link, I don't have a github acc.

Comment: I came to understand your problem. You should use `anchor` tag for this. This is your only option. `<a onClick={()=>window.location.reload()} href="/home" >Home</a>`